# error while joining DB tables, Integrity constraint violation

Tags: join, laravel, inner-join

I have 3 tables product, brand and product_media.

**product:** skuid(int)(pk), brand_id(int)

**brand:** id(int)(pk), brand_name(varchar)

**product_media:** id(int)(pk), skuid(int)(fk), product_img(varchar)

DB Query

```
$result = DB::table('product')
           ->join('brand', 'product.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id')
           ->join('product_media', 'product.skuid', '=', 'product_media.skuid')
           ->select('product.skuid', 'brand.brand_name', 'product_media.product_img')
           ->where('skuid')->get();
```

I am getting an error saying "Integrity constraint violation, Column 'skuid' in where clause is ambiguous"

can anyone help me fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your last line, `->where('skuid')->get();` just specify a table. Something like :

`->where('product.skuid')->get();`